# mplayer: Problem opening sound files, gnome-mplyaer works, why?

Tags: gnome, audio, alsa, mplayer, mp3

I'm new to this community and this is my first question.

I am using Debian 8.3 Jessie and have two sound files `a.mp3` and `b.mp3` on my hard drive. I am using mplayer and gnome-mplayer to open these files.

I acquired both files from an outside source.

**Problem:**
If I open `a.mp3` in mplayer the output is distorted and stuttering + here and there a high pitched blip (sounds like damaged mp3 file). However, if I open file `a.mp3` in GNOME-MPLAYER it plays fine. File `b.mp3` doesn't show this behavior and plays fine in mplayer and gnome-mplayer.

I also tried to convert the problematic file (`a.mp3`) to an ogg file with avconv but that didn't help either.

Opening file `a.mp3` in iceweasle also works fine.
The issue is limited to mplayer only.

What am I donig wrong?

**Metadata of files:**
*a.mp3*

```
avprobe version 11.6-6:11.6-1~deb8u1, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar  2 2016 23:00:02 with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
[mp3 @ 0xd27d20] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached
Input #0, mp3, from 'a.mp3':
  Metadata:
    track           : 1
  Duration: 00:06:25.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.99r
```

*b.mp3*

```
avprobe version 11.6-6:11.6-1~deb8u1, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar  2 2016 23:00:02 with gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
[mp3 @ 0x122cd20] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached
Input #0, mp3, from 'b.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : dash
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: iso6mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
  Duration: 00:03:58.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 115 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16p, 115 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26
```

Requested Information:
**mplayer output of playing a.mp3**

```
MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4+b1 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
Cannot open file '/home/mr/.mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
Failed to open /home/mr/.mplayer/input.conf.
Cannot open file '/etc/mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
Failed to open /etc/mplayer/input.conf.

Playing a.mp3.
Detected file format: MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3) (libavformat)
[mp3 @ 0x7fb48d85fb40]max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached
[lavf] stream 0: audio (mp3), -aid 0
Clip info:
 track: 1
Load subtitles in .
Selected audio codec: MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 layers I, II, III [mpg123]
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 128.0 kbit/8.33% (ratio: 16000->192000)
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
Starting playback...
```

**mplayer output of playing b.mp3**

```
Playing b.mp3.
Detected file format: MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3) (libavformat)
[mp3 @ 0x7f30481d9b40]max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached
[lavf] stream 0: audio (mp3), -aid 0
Clip info:
 major_brand: dash
 minor_version: 0
 compatible_brands: iso6mp41
 encoder: Lavf56.25.101
Load subtitles in .
Selected audio codec: MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 layers I, II, III [mpg123]
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 32.0 kbit/2.27% (ratio: 4000->176400)
AO: [pulse] 44100Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Video: no video
Starting playback...
```

**~/.mplayer/config**

```
vo=gl
```

**EDIT**
The problem only exists when I play file `a.mp3` over the analog output of the Thinkpad T420 while a pair of USB-headphones is plugged in at the same time which is not used for any playback.
[image: Spectrograph]
Upper spectrograph: file `a.mp3` when played over analog output with USB-headphones plugged in (recorded from analog output). Notice the very high peak slightly above and left to the arrow, that's about 8kHz.
Lower spectrograph: file `a.mp3` when loaded directly into audacity.

lsusb with headphones
`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:0a45 Logitech, Inc`

**--- IMPORTANT EDIT ---**
as of now (2016-03-25) the problem is gone. Playing any mp3 file works as it should over any output attached to the computer (USB headphones, USB sound card, internal sound card). However I don't know why...

Comment: Please post the full output of running `mplayer a.mp3` and `mplayer b.mp3`. What output are mplayer and gnome-mplayer using (`ao_…` options, especially `ao_driver`)? Note that `mplayer` and `gnome-mplayer` use a different configuration file (`~/.mplayer/config` for `mplayer`, `~/.config/gnome-mplayer` for `gnome-mplayer`), a difference between the two could be due to different settings. I don't know what settings could cause problems with some files but not others but that's something to investigate.

Comment: the output would be too long to be posted as a comment, I'm editing the question instead.

Comment: `~/.config/gnome-mplayer` is a folder that contains a SQLite database with recently played files and subfolders with cover art and Plugins (wich is empty).

Comment: I've found something even more disturbing about this issue.
I'm on a Thinkpad T420 (Debian 8.3) and listen to music through the  analog output (Headphones) connected to an amplifier. At the same time I've a pair of Logitech USB-headphones plugged in. When I unplug them, everything works as it's supposed to be!

Comment: So perhaps you're drawing too much from the Thinkpad's audio source (likely: Conexant sound chip), and/or establishing a notable impedance mismatch?  Laptops aren't renown for coming with a standard for superior audio sources.

Comment: No, because it works with other mp3-files + it only happens when the USB-headphones are plugged in + with the headphones plugged in `a.mp3` doesn't work but `b.mp3` does. The electrical aspect is working fine.
The problem sounds crazy, even unsolvable.

Comment: There's too much missing information about the potential differences between your "a.mp3" and "b.mp3".   I could create enough dynamic range in one mp3 which made it all but inaudible with any of the headphones i own, (and no, mp3 do not compress dynamic range, they compress data).  As my final palaver, i'd consider getting some tools by which you can analyze your two mp3 files, for internal consistency as well as statistical differences; at least before declaring anything to be "unsolvable".

Comment: Well "unsolvable" was to quick.
I don't think the issue is the audibility.
If I damage another, working mp3-file on purpose, it sounds similar. It has high bleeps and sweeps, but they only occur in mplayer.
But the point is, It's not a damaged mp3-file.

Comment: I've added more info to the question.